# Encoding error?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, encoding, glassfish

I am ussing JSF 2.0 in combination with Primefaces and when i use a component called dataTable, i see this in my eclipse console when i refresh the page.

```
SEVERE: line 1:61 no viable alternative at character ';'
```

I think this is the reason why some features of this component are not working properly. 
This are the links to another 2 questions that i think i can solve if i solve this problem:

[JSF 2.0 can't render dialog from primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489711/jsf-2-0-problem-rendering-dialog-from-primefaces)

[dataTable sorting problem (JSF2.0 + primefaces)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487752/sorting-a-datatable-strange-behavior-jsf2-0-primefaces)

Does this message have something to do with encoding?

Is this some kind of compatibility issue?(I use Glassfish server 3.0)

I tried to change the ecoding types of the files faces-config.xml and sun-web.xml from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 but that did not solve anything. Did someone saw this message before and know what is it about? i cant find useful information in google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your previous questions it looks like the error message is caused by the extra `;` in a named query, therefore it's not related to your JSF problem:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findAllGarbage", 
    query = "SELECT g.filename, g.description, g.uploadDate FROM Garbage g;")
```

Comment: Yes the error went away. Please forgive me. Thank you very much that was diving me crazy :) At least now i know the other errors have nothing to do with that.